# Cannot connect to Oracle databse from Toad 9.0

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-connection, toad

I am using Oracle 10g version 10.0.2

Few days ago I was able to connect to my database using SQLPlus and Toad 9.0
Without changing anything, now Im not able to connect to my database from Toad with the following error msg:
"You have no Oracle client Installed", but Im still able to connect to the database and to perform queries from SQLPlus

So, please what may cause this problem!?

Comment: Is your Oracle Home variable set?

Comment: @Nick excuse me, but what do you mean exactly by Home variable? if you mean the environment PATH variable, so the answer is Yes

Comment: The reason I ask, is because it looks like Toad can't find where your Oracle client is installed.  I'm pretty sure it uses the ORACLE_HOME environment variable to find the installation.

Comment: If this is Windows (I assume so because of TOAD) then ORACLE_HOME is managed in the registry, and you'll likely mess things up for yourself if you set it in the windows environment.

Comment: What version of Windows? 32 or 64 bit? Are you using the oracle client, or a full install of the database? Is your database on the same system as the client? Is the Oracle installation 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [Quest support site](https://support.quest.com/Search/SolutionDetail.aspx?ID=SOL39689)?

This is apparently a relatively common occurrence with TOAD. Some of it seems to be related to using the 64 bit client, or with an installation in a directory path with parentheses in it. I don't quite get the fact it worked earlier, though.

Is installing the latest version of TOAD an option?